# Bits flipped between my webassembly binary and my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, rust, bit, webassembly

**Rust Web Assembly code**

```
let size = (width * height) as usize;
let mut cells = FixedBitSet::with_capacity(size);

for i in 0..size {
    cells.set(i, i == 0);
}
```

**Javascript code**

Converting bits from memory buffer to a javascript 8-bit array

```
const cells = new Uint8Array(memory.buffer, cellsPtr, (width * height) / 8);
```

When I print the FixedBitSet, I get the following:

```
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

When I print the javascript array I get:

```
[ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, … ]
```

Meaning javascript is interpreting it as `00000001`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: it's look like the program is working properly. you set first bit of first value to 1 which means that in js you will get that first value of array will be equal to 1 (output of bitset print is looks so because you print values from first to last from left to right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not looked at the code of `FixedBitSet`, but I would assume that internally it's a buffer of integers and it just uses shifts to address each bit.

This means the simplest implementation would be that bit n is in element `n / k` (where `k` is the number of bits in whatever integer size it picked), then shifted by `n % k`.

For the sake of arguments let's assume `k = 8` (aka the FBS uses bytes internally), bytes are traditionally *printed* in big-endian, meaning the most significant bit first and the least significant bit last.

Given a bitset of size 32:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

you're setting bit 0, `n / k = 0` and `n % k = 0`, the first bit of the first byte is going to be... the right-most one:

```
00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

which, interpreted as an array of u8, is `[1, 0, 0, 0]`.

Now I don't know if that's what happens internally in `FixedBitSet`, but it seems like the most straightforward implementation.

And because WebAssembly is defined as a little endian virtual machine the exact same behaviour would occur even if FBS uses wider integers e.g. if it's u32, bit 0 would be the least significant bit (= last bit) of the least significant byte (= first byte).